# How to parse html page from POCO websocket server?

Tags: c++, html, websocket, poco

I am writing a websocket server using POCO, following the sample in the POCO documentation, i can generate html page from the sever like this

```
    class PageRequestHandler: public HTTPRequestHandler
    /// Return a HTML document with some JavaScript creating
    /// a WebSocket connection.
{
public:
    void handleRequest(HTTPServerRequest& request, HTTPServerResponse& response)
    {
        response.setChunkedTransferEncoding(true);
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        std::ostream& ostr = response.send();
        ostr << "<html>";
        ostr << "<head>";
        ostr << "<title>WebSocketServer</title>";
        ostr << "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
        ostr << "function WebSocketTest()";
        ostr << "{";
        ostr << "  if (\"WebSocket\" in window)";
        ostr << "  {";
        ostr << "    var ws = new WebSocket(\"ws://" << request.serverAddress().toString() << "/ws\");";
        ostr << "    ws.onopen = function()";
        ostr << "      {";
        ostr << "        ws.send(\"Hello, world!\");";
        ostr << "      };";
        ostr << "    ws.onmessage = function(evt)";
        ostr << "      { ";
        ostr << "        var msg = evt.data;";
        ostr << "        alert(\"Message received: \" + msg);";
        ostr << "        ws.close();";
        ostr << "      };";
        ostr << "    ws.onclose = function()";
        ostr << "      { ";
        ostr << "        alert(\"WebSocket closed.\");";
        ostr << "      };";
        ostr << "  }";
        ostr << "  else";
        ostr << "  {";
        ostr << "     alert(\"This browser does not support WebSockets.\");";
        ostr << "  }";
        ostr << "}";
        ostr << "</script>";
        ostr << "</head>";
        ostr << "<body>";
        ostr << "  <h1>WebSocket Server</h1>";
        ostr << "  <p><a href=\"javascript:WebSocketTest()\">Run WebSocket Script</a></p>";
        ostr << "</body>";
        ostr << "</html>";
    }
};
```

and when i can in my navigator the server like this  `http://127.0.0.1:9980/` i get the generated page .

Now my problem is that i want to to call a specific page form my navigator like this `http://127.0.0.1:9980/index.html` .

I tried to call the web socket,after lunching the websocket server, from a page by adding an event that calls the websocket address like this

```
function myFunction()
{

     var soc_di="ws://127.0.0.1:9980/ws"
//var soc_di;

   // soc_di  = new WebSocket(get_appropriate_ws_url(),
    //       "send-protocol");
  try {
    soc_di.onopen = function() {
      //document.getElementById("wsdi_statustd").style.backgroundColor = "#40ff40";
      document.getElementById("demo").textContent = " websocket connection opened ";
    } 

    soc_di.onmessage =function got_packet(msg) {
      //document.getElementById("number").textContent = msg.data + "\n";
      document.getElementById("des").textContent = msg.data + "\n";
    } 

    soc_di.onclose = function(){
      //document.getElementById("wsdi_statustd").style.backgroundColor = "#ff4040";
      document.getElementById("demo").textContent = " websocket connection CLOSED ";
    }
  } catch(exception) {
    alert('<p>Error' + exception);  
  }

}
```

Could any one show me what i did wrong??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -3):

You may find the answer here: https://github.com/paulreimer/ofxWebUI/blob/master/src/ofxWebUIRequestHandler.h

Basically what you need to do is to get this string:

```
std::string url = request.getURI();
```